# How to truncate file with new size> 2 GB on Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to truncate a file with  with new size >2Gb (on Android) but it is not working (on computer, it is ok).

My code:

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
f.setLength(f.length()-512); //file length 3Gb (exception EINVAL invalid argument)
f.close();
```

I found a solution (use truncate64() method) but I don't know how to use it on Android (I don't found file .so lib have truncate64 too). Help me!

Comment: I can see no reason why the `setLength()` method shouldn't be able to handle files in excess of 2GB. Is this the actual code you are using?

Comment: Yes, I am using this code and I also tried:
<pre><code>FileChannel outChan = new FileOutputStream (new File (filename), true) .getChannel ();
outChan.truncate (newLength);
outChan.close ();</code>

Comment: Try using `f.setLength(512)` on your 3GB file and see if that truncates it (isolate if the problem is truncating a large file itself, or something to do with the size you are specifying).

Comment: oh sorry, I mean newlength> 2GB

Comment: Then try `f.setLength(2000000000L)` on a file and see if that works.

Comment: I just want to truncate a small portion of data redundancy without losing the original data of the file. You have tried to 2000000000L (less than 2GB of data), it will still operate normally, but with file size >2GB (ex: file 3000000512L you cut 512 bytes => 3000000512L-512L = 3000000000L) you will see an error more specifically

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant try `f.setLength(3000000000L)`. Just trying to get the bottom of the issue - does providing an absolute value work? Want to rule out possibility of the problem coming from the `f.length()` part of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are using

```
filename.length-512
```

You are looking at the length of the String `filename` instead of looking at the length of the file.

What you probably want to do instead is

```
f.setLength(f.length()-512);
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong, do not bother about the code that the main issue here is truncate by setLength (> 2Gb) on Android

Comment: You might want to edit your question to have the code with exactly what you are running.